# How to get last value from the list and store in another

Tags: java

Actually I am reading the value from the file,file data are given below ,now the  requirement is get the first value and last value and get the total number of value present in the file.

```
below is my approach
String[] obj = line.split(splitBy);//reading the content
List<String>list=Arrays.asList(obj);
System.out.println("--><"+list.get(1));//getting the value
System.out.println("-->"+ list.get(list.size() - 1));//this is returning last value of a line.
```

**file**

```
line1 89482
line2 89490
line3 89491
line4 89492
line5 89493
line6 89494
```

**actuall file value is**

```
Cloud
Batch D


*******

*      

*******

var_out
8946270
8946270
8946270
8946270
8946270
8946270
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What problem you are facing?

Comment: m not able to get last value from last line.

Comment: Post your array obj value here.

Comment: System.out.println("--><"+list.get(1));//getting the value.. change this to list.get(0);

Comment: What exception you got when you trying to get the last value from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check list is empty or not, if list is not empty then it will print the last element.

```
if(!list.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> now the requirement is get the first value and last value and get the
>   total number of value present in the file.

First Value - `list.get(0)`

Last Value - `list.get(list.size()-1)`

size - `list.size()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Hi");
        list.add("hii");
        list.add("hiii");
        System.out.println("First Value : = "+list.get(0));
        System.out.println("Last Value : = "+list.get(list.size()-1));
        System.out.println("Size : = "+list.size());
    }
```

**output**

```
First Value : = Hi
Last Value : = hiii
Size : = 3
```

Comment: try to get last line value.

Comment: @abcC what is `last line` according to you

Comment: file can contain more or less line.

Comment: @abcC so `list.get(list.size()-1)` will always return the last element, irrespective of how many lines are there, what doubt you have.